# Fetch results from prepared SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am making a php document the logs the user in if they are in the database and entered the correct username and password. To be secure I am using prepared statements but I can't get the results from my SELECT query to set session variables necessary for my site. Here is my code...

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'config.php'; #This file has all connection info 
#$C is the mysqli connection
#$USERS is the name of the table in my database
$sql = $C->prepare('SELECT ID,Username,Favorites FROM '.$USERS.' WHERE Email=? AND Password=PASSWORD(?)');
$sql->bind_param("ss", $e,$p);

$e = $_POST['e'];#email
$p = $_POST['p'];#password

$query = $sql->execute();
$sql->store_result();
$numrows = $sql->num_rows;
if($numrows == 1) {
    $sql->bind_result($id,$username,$favs);
    while($sql->fetch()) {
        $_SESSION['ID'] = $id;
        $_SESSION['Name'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['favs'] = $favs;
        $_SESSION['valid'] = true;
    }
    echo 'true';
}
else {
    echo 'User Not Found';
}
```

This just echoes 'User Not Found' because $numrows always = 0 and I made sure that all the entered info was correct.

Comment: Also do some debug `var_dump` or `print_r` to test your query.

Comment: It should be  `$query->>bind_result($id,$username,$favs);` instead of `$sql->...`

Comment: @Mihai you are wrong

Comment: In regard of fetching the result from a prepared statement your code is all right. There is nothing to answer.

Why doesn't it return any data is another question which is off topic for this site. Frankly, we cannot know.

Comment: Your query doesnt find any rows,check those bind variables,also run your query hardcoded

Comment: Sorry everybody I found my mistake, it was not in this document sorry for all the confusion, thank you all for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Move the variable assignments to $e and $p above the call to bind_params or at least declare them above the call.

The parameters to bind_params are passed by reference, so changes to the variables after bind but before execute take effect, but AFAIK the variables have to exist before the bind call.

Comment: Could downvoters please explain their reasons to help me understand why my answer is not good or even incorrect?

Comment: Probably DV'ed because you are spreading misinformation.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/2961222/2943403  Moving the declarations of `$e` and `$p` to before the `bind_params()` call will in no way resolve any encountered problems.  This answer cannot possibly be the answer to the experienced problem.