# MYSQLi Prepared Statements not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

MySQLi with Prepared Statements error inserting

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email,password) VALUES (?, ?, ? ,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssss",$firstname,$lastname,$email,$pass); //<-- return 500 status

// // set parameters and execute
$firstname = "John";
$lastname = "Doe";
$email = "john@example.com";
$pass = "Doe";

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: You set the parameters after you bind them???? How should that work?

Comment: And also why do you bind 5 parameters instead of 4?

Comment: @ElChupacabra where do you see 5?

Comment: @ElChupacabra  i added four parameter plz check it ..

Comment: check your logs and get the real errors to show up if you don't have access to logs and check your connection

Comment: My fault I forget that first param of bind_param is for types.

Comment: @Fred-ii-   it shows HTTP status 500  , is there problem with MYSQL V 14.14  . kindly help me to reslove

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @PankajMakwana  i am getting HTTP status 500   ($stmt->bind_param("ssss",$firstname,$lastname,$email,$pass);)

Comment: can you please show `users` table

Comment: @PankajMakwana  sorry guys very worst mistake , column name mismatched , now it is working ,  event thought i could not figure out my exact exception , i tried lot ...  again thanks  all

Comment: I'd delete the question if you ask me. None of the answers given solved this. What did solve it, was checking for the real error.

Comment: @juergend https://stackoverflow.com/a/2961267/2943403

Answer (score 0):

I like using the placeholders, give it a try!

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email,password) 
VALUES (:first, :last, :email , :pass)";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindValue('first', $firstName);
$stmt->bindValue('last', $lastName);
$stmt->bindValue('email', $email);
$stmt->bindValue('pass', $password);

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Firstly, you didn't tell the OP to change their "connection" to PDO, so they might not know or know what to do. Second; while this might work for them, it doesn't explain the problem in the first place.

Comment: @delboy   you're  post PDO with Prepared Statements  but i am  using MySQLi with Prepared Statements  , which one prefer for mycase

Comment: murugesh, oh yes, I put `bindValue` there, which is PDO. Apologies! I take it mysqli doesn't use the placeholders? It's been so long since I changed over!

Comment: Evidently, this question is Off-topic Typo -- indication: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46341029/mysqli-prepared-statements-not-working#comment79642883_46341029